# Why does my for/in loop give me null results, but my regular for loop doesn't (PICTURES)?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to iterate an array of objects using a for/in loop to log some of the properties of each object to the Chrome dev console, but I keep getting null values. I then decided to use a regular for loop, and I received the values I expected in the dev console.

Could some explain to me why the for/in is giving me null values when the regular for loops gives me the expected (non-null) values?

This is the code:

```
watch: {
    events() {
        console.log(this.events)

        for(let event in this.events) {
            console.log(`Lat: ${event.latitude}, Lng: ${event.longitude}`)
        }

        for(let i = 0; i < this.events.length; i++) {
            console.log(`Lat: ${this.events[i].latitude}, Lng: ${this.events[i].longitude}`)
        }
    }
}
```

Picture for reference:
[Console log output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YmbY.jpg)

The first output in the picture in the link is the array, the second is the for/in loop values (the one with the "10" beside it), and values after that are the values from the regular for loop.

Comment: `for...in` is for iterating over object properties, not for iterating over arrays. Use `for...of` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for...in` is for [iterating over object properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in), not for iterating over arrays. Use [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) instead:

```
watch: {
    events() {
        console.log(this.events)

        for(const event of this.events) {
            console.log(`Lat: ${event.latitude}, Lng: ${event.longitude}`)
        }

        for(let i = 0; i < this.events.length; i++) {
            console.log(`Lat: ${this.events[i].latitude}, Lng: ${this.events[i].longitude}`)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please read the documentation of for..in. This will return the enumerable properties. which in the case of arrays is array indexes. so you have to still do `this.events[index]` to get the actual event.

Also, the order is not guaranteed ans is purely dependent on implementation. So you have to be careful. More on this at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Array_iteration_and_for...in

Answer (score 0):

for/in return indexes as string if use for Arrays, 
Refer here :https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Answer (score 0):

for/in iterates over every element in an array, with no defined order but the iterator is still just an array index.  You probably want to be using for/of.  Remember: **i**n is **i**ndex, **o**f is **o**bject

```js
var events = [ { latitude: "10", longitude: "100" }
             , { latitude: "11", longitude: "101" }
             ];

console.log(events);

console.log('for/in:');
for(let event in events) {
    console.log(`Lat: ${events[event].latitude}, Lng: ${events[event].longitude}`)
}

console.log('for/of:');
for(event of events) {
    console.log(`Lat: ${event.latitude}, Lng: ${event.longitude}`);
}
```